# How to restart a daemon file when it is crashed

Tags: php, linux

Frds I am new to linux. I am running a php daemon script. Its working fine. But sometime unfortunately it is getting stopped without any intimation. I want that daemon to be started immediately when it is getting crashed.

Can i check the crashed daemon php file  using another daemon and if it is crashed can i restart that.

If yes please tell me how to do that. I am new to command line. But i am ok with PHP codings.

Comment: Certainly you can do that. But I guess this is not your real question...

Comment: This is my real questoin. i want the daemon to run continuously without any crash.

Comment: That is a contradiction: either you want to have it run continuously or you want to restart it because it has crashed. Now what? May I suggest you find out _why_ that script "crashes"? It certainly does not do that without any reason.

Comment: good question you have asked.

Comment: I suggest you tell us what script / daemon that is.

Comment: daemon related to user removal. If there is more load it gets crashed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49563/discussion-between-arkascha-and-vinoth-babu)